# ECS Task Deregistering

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-ecs

I have an ECS Cluster and 1 microserver running in it, now the login function code written in the server is making my ECS Task fail its health check, due to which the Task is deregistering and shutting down, all the routes are working fine, but the login route is causing the Task to fail health check, but it is working fine on local, I am new to AWS ECS, Has anyone got any idea why this may be happening, or how to solve it.
Please do tell, if I need to share some code from my end, as I said I am new so I don't know what to share.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your load balancer is being blocked by the authentication page when it attempts to perform a health check. You either need to provide a page for the load balancer's health check that doesn't require authentication, or modify the load balancer's health check settings to accept the login page.

I'm guessing it is probably getting a redirect response from the server, due to being unauthenticated, and the load balancer isn't configured to accept a redirect response.

Comment: Any resources on how to do what exactly? How to set the load balancer health check settings? Have you read the official documentation yet? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/target-group-health-checks.html

Comment: yes, I could not find anything relevant, will take a look at the link you shared.

Answer (score -1):

two thing you need to check if your task is properly register with iam user
or iam user is not able to interact with task see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/APIReference/API_RegisterTaskDefinition.html

to check if your task is regster properly or your iam user able to execute it or not see this
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_execution_IAM_role.html

Comment: if still problem is exists you can ping me here!